# What imports and script tags are required for Polymer.dart 1.0.0-rcx

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

What imports and script tags are required to make an client app using Polymer.dart work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <script src="packages/web_components/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body unresolved>
    <my-element></my-element>
    <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- The `webcomponents-lite.min.js` script adds the Polymer polyfills.
- The `dart.js` is necessary for every Dart browser application to run in browsers without Dart VM.
- The `index.dart` contains your custom `main();` and imports `<my-element>` using `@HtmlImports(...)`

where `index.dart` contains

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'my_element.dart';

/// Silence analyzer [MyElement]
main() async {
  await initPolymer();
}
```

Without a custom main

import elements using `<link rel="import" ...>` (discouraged)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <script src="packages/web_components/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="my_element.html">
  </head>
  <body unresolved>
    <my-element></my-element>
    <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

or using `@HtmlImport(...)` for importing elements

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <script src="packages/web_components/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body unresolved>
    <my-element></my-element>
    <script type="application/dart">
      export 'package:polymer/init.dart';
      import 'my_element.dart';
    </script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Hint:**
Without an explicit script tag for main it's more difficult to register the entry-point for the reflectable transformer. Some name for a generated file can be used instead but I don't know yet what this files name is.